# https to http redirect not working godaddy shared hosting

Tags: .htaccess, https

I do not have any ssl certificate. So I am trying to redirect the domain with https to http using .htacces. But it is not working. Instead domain with https is showing godaddy's default coming soon page.

Answer (score 0):

If you use apache, you can enter the following in a .htaccess file or in your apache configuration:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: The OP had worse problems: no control over the https content at all.
Moreover the redirect will do little in modern browsers if the https site has no SSL certificate (not that those aren't available for free - so there's really no excuse to not use https in all honesty.